# CSS Help. Open expanding div without pushing content below down

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

Based on the image, picture 1 is the closed state. Once the user expands the green div in the second panel, the content below (blue) gets pushed down too. Is there a way using **only** CSS I can open the green div without pushing the blue content down?

I am using a third party component, so I have no ability to change the HTML so I can only use CSS.

Currently the 3 divs are wrapped in another div with `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide some HTML-code, so that we know how we can use CSS? If the items are wrappers for a content-element, then you could simply use `position: absolute` for the content so that it won't interact with the flow when expanding. Otherwise I would suggest to use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into CSS grid, it is by far the best way for beginners to learn to size divs by using columns and rows. You will have to set the width and height of any div for it to not resize, or else content will just move based on what's inside them, which is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

css grid should do the trick

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 400px;
  align-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```